# Вставить элемент после n-го элемента списка

Tags: c++, list

Не знаю, что делать дальше, список сформировал, а как вставить элемент после указанного не пойму. Помогите, пожалуйста.

Вот код:

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;


//Описание типа узла стека.
struct Node {
Node *next;                       
char ch;                         
Node(): next(NULL),ch(0){}                  
Node(Node *p, char tch): next(p),ch(tch){}  

};
//-------------------------------------------------------------------

void push(Node **pptop , char tch);    //добавление на вершину стека.
void pop(Node**pptop);                 //выборка из вершины стека.

void update(Node**pptop);              //освобождение памяти из под стека.
void print(Node *ptop);                //вывести стек.

void input(Node **pptop);              //ввод стека.
void insert(Node *ptop);               //вставить в стек.

inline char get_top(Node *ptop){ return ptop->ch; }
//-------------------------------------------------------------------

//Главная функция.
int main(){
Node *top = NULL;   //клиентский указатель на вершину стека.
  input(&top);        //вводим  стек.

  print(top);         //выводим стек.
  insert(top);        //вставляем после минимального.
  print(top);         //опять выводим стек.


update(&top);       //освобождаем память, если она была выделена.

system("pause");
return 0;
}

//------------------------------------------------------------------

//добавление на вершину стека.
void push(Node **pptop , char tch){
Node *p = new Node(*pptop,tch);        
*pptop = p;                            
}

//выборка из вершины стека.
void pop(Node**pptop){

    //Если стек создан: указатель вершины не NULL.
    if(*pptop){
      char t = (*pptop)->ch;     
          Node *pd = *pptop;         
         (*pptop)=(*pptop)->next;  
         delete pd;                   

    pd = NULL;

    }




}



//освобождение памяти из под стека.
void update(Node**pptop){ while(*pptop)pop(pptop);  }

//вывести стек.           
void print(Node *ptop){

   while(ptop){
      cout<<ptop->ch<<endl;    
      ptop=ptop->next;           
   }
cout<<endl;
}

//ввод стека.
void input(Node **pptop){

    unsigned int i(0);
    char data(0);
    cout<<"inputs: "; cin>>i;            
    while(i){
      cout<<"input data: " ; cin>>data;  
          push(pptop,data);                  
          i--;
    }




}
```